# Sharepoint online WIKI page content size limit

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

Is there any limit for Content inside Sharepointonline wiki page.

Also How can we make wiki page content into sharepoint search.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as "limit on content inside SharePoint online wiki page" is concerned, there is not limit as the content inside wiki page would be stored in Content DB in binary form.

By default content of wiki page is indexed into SharePoint search results, did you experience where in wiki page is not displaying in search results with target keyword.

Hope this helps!!